# iOS Authorize Dropbox without opening Dropbox app

Tags: ios, ios6, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to iOS Authorize Dropbox without opening Dropbox app if it is installed.  Just open the Dropbox webview.  You were able to do this for facebook authentication, I was hoping there is a option I can set to not open the dropbox app.

I found the auth api logic
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#authorize

Not sure how you would implement it for iOS.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify - is the problem that you don't know how to "hand off" the authenticated session to the webview, or that you don't know how to authenticate the user *outside of the webview* in the first place?

Comment: The problem is that if the user has the dropbox app installed, I don't want the "[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];" to open the dropbox app.  I want the authentication to use the webview.

Comment: @TimWalsh, did you ever find a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: I put this on the back burner, but looks like the API will allow you to write your own login page.  I will end up doing that instead of adding another 3rd party library like Temboo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this by checking if Drop box is installed and changing the call based off that.

```
    NSURL *dropboxUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"dbapi-1://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:dropboxUrl]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkUserId:@"" fromController:vc];
    }else{
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:vc];
    }
```

If the user has dropbox installed, then it will open safari and validate the user that way.

Not the cleanest solution, but the best solution without adding any more 3rd party libs.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot Tim. I'll go ahead and use your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question in the comments up there, and your answer may or may not render this answer invalid but here you go:  You can leverage Dropbox's own [iOS SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdk) to authenticate the current user.  This is probably preferable to using the `/authentication` REST endpoint.

Another option which may very well make life easier is to use Temboo's [iOS SDK](https://www.temboo.com/download) *(full disclosure: I work for Temboo)*.  It allows you to work with [Dropbox's API](https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Dropbox/) very easily in your iOS app, and your Temboo account tools additionally handle a lot of the heavy lifting around OAuth, credentials, etc.  There are [100+ other APIs](https://live.temboo.com/library/) the Temboo SDK can talk to as well, and once you've implemented one integrating with other APIs is a breeze.

Cheers